# Calling Posted Array in PHP And SQL

Tags: php, sql

I'm naming my input fields as their row value in the input radio button in my database. What I'm having trouble with is calling that name inside of the $_Post[ ] brackets. How would I accomplish this?

Select Statement

```
$getQuestions = "
    SELECT
        *

    FROM
        questions
    WHERE questions.active = '1'

    ORDER BY
        questionID
";
```

PHP Code

```
if ($aRow['correct'] == 1) {
 $tableString .="<input name=". $qRow['questionID'] ." type='radio'>" .


$question = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$qRow['questionID']][$i]);
```

Comment: information incomplete

Comment: @VforVendetta I added sql select statement where I get the questions if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so I got to write it here.

When your code doesn't work, always debug it first, check what's inside variables that may give you a clue on what to do and in this case I think you could dump $_POST and $qRow and see what they contain, so put this code:

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($qRow);
```

before:

```
$question = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$qRow['questionID']][$i]);
```

If it didn't help you to figure it out, then just post the result of those dumps

Comment: When i dump post it returns array(3) { [1]=> string(2) "on" [2]=> string(2) "on" [3]=> string(2) "on" } . When a question is entered into my database it receives an auto incremented value such as 1,2,3 ect. as the primary key and the name of the input is named what the value is. What I'm having trouble doing is figuring out what to type into the post brackets inside of $question where I wouldn't have to manually type out each value.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do but maybe $question = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$qRow['questionID']]);